# Singing while playing guitar

Tags: guitar, voice, improvisation

I want to sing while I am playing guitar.
either I miss the strum or I miss the tempo of my voice. How can I combine these two?

Comment: You just have to be patient and practice a lot to gain independence. Imagine someone eating for the first time with a fork! If you involve him/her into a conversation at the same time this might get messy ;-) CAUTION !!! Try to use a fork - or better take a spoon - with your left hand...

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might help you is to practice them separately. First learn the guitar part; you should be able to play it fluently without thinking about what you play. You should be able to play the guitar and talk to someone. After you've mastered that, you can practice adding the singing part. If you have the guitar part fluently, it will  come easier. If not, try to learn the sing part on its own. After you've mastered this one as well, add it to the guitar strumming and practice them together.

Comment: If you can talk while you play, you can definitely sing, but you might be able to sing even if you can't talk if the rhythms match well enough.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Definitely! I would even say that it's more of a challenge to talk freely than to sing rhythmically. Give it a try! That's why guitar players always cast a hollow glance at you when you are talking to them or when they try to speak while playing - they are focusing on their strumming... ;-)